# 3D application fails to run on Intel i3-2120

Tags: opengl-es

I have a Virtual machine running Ubuntu on my windows7 PC. The machine has Intel i3-2120 processor. So I suppose it has support for OpenGL APIs as the processor has in-built Intel HD Graphics 2000 GPU.

I am using OpenGL ES 2.0 Emulator from ARM to build and run 3D application. I am new to OpenGL ES. I had built a cube application which comes with the example in Emulator itself just to test whether if the setup is ready to run 3D application.

The application does not run and it fails in compiling the shader in the below steps:

```
  GL_CHECK(glCompileShader(*pShader));
  GL_CHECK(glGetShaderiv(*pShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &iStatus));
```

Is this issue somewhere related to hardware? Could someone please help in figuring out what is wrong here with the setup?

Thanks!!

Comment: You need to check the shader infolog if the shader fails to compile:
 [glGetShaderInfoLog()](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGetShaderInfoLog.xml). It should tell you why it fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have any errors in shader code, it should be due to virtualisation. Check if you have 3D acceleration support on you ubuntu.

Execute this in terminal: glxinfo | grep rendering

If you get "direct rendering: No", there is your problem. Check if your virtualisation application supports 3D acceleration and how to enable it.